# How to find all Git commits between 2 latest tags matching a certain format (e.g. of a PROD deployment)

Tags: git, continuous-integration, cicd

Prod deployments are tagged e.g. with "prod/0.1.123" by the CDI pipeline.

Often the question arises, "What is contained in the current deployment?" or "What changed in the last deployment?". Is there a single Git command to answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with this:

```
git log --oneline --pretty=format:"%s (%cn - %ci)" $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 --match "prod/*" $(git rev-list --tags="prod/*" --max-count=1 --skip=1))..$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 --match "prod/*")
```

It finds last tag starting with "prod/" and previous one and outputs all commit messages one-lined and pretty formatted like this:

```
#hash <message> (<author> - <date>)
```

If you want also tags (like those from Dev deployment) contained and just the hash+message you can also omit the *--pretty-format* part. Or for even more details use: *-pretty=medium*

Comment: Bonus: If you want to know what happened since last PROD deployment (= tagged commit) use this -> git log --oneline $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 --match "prod/*")..HEAD

Comment: no need for `--oneline` if you provide an explicit `--pretty=...`

Answer (score -1):

To list the commits that landed on `origin/main` since tag `prod/0.1.123`:

```
git log --oneline prod/0.1.123..origin/main

# or with a custom format:
git log --pretty=format:"..." prod/0.1.123..origin/main
```

---

If you want to list tags starting with `prod/` :

```
git tag --list "prod/*"
```

To sort them by treating `0.1.10` as a version number (e.g: `0.1.10` should appear *after* `0.1.2`, not before), you can use `--sort=version:refname` :

```
git tag --sort="version:refname" --list "prod/*"

# to get the latest one:
git tag --sort="version:refname" --list "prod/*" | tail -1
```

---

combining the two:

```
lasttag=$(git tag --sort="version:refname" --list "prod/*" | tail -1)
git log --oneline ${lasttag}..origin/main

# or as a one liner:
git log --oneline $(git tag --sort="version:refname" --list "prod/*" | tail -1)..origin/main
```

Comment: The solution should be generic without knowledge of the exact tag - here you already know the tag. Pattern should match "prod/*".